# Webpack. Как обратиться к JSON?

Tags: json, webpack

Webpack с версии 2+ автоматически собирает импорты с файлами JSON. В собранном js-файле база данных существует, но как к ней правильно обратиться?

Или единственный способ - вручную закидывать в dist папку с json-ами?

Comment: Эм, просто сделать import в нужном месте в коде? Не совсем понятно в чём проблема

Comment: @andreymal как потом прописать путь в fetch к этому json?

Comment: Если он в собранном js-файле существает, значит никакой fetch не нужен, достаточно простого import. Или у вас задача убрать его из js-файла?

Comment: @andreymal задача в том, чтобы взаимодействовать с этими данными - менять, удалять и всё такое. Просто это ведь получается как массив без названия, как тогда к нему обратиться?

Comment: Так просто дайте ему какое-нибудь название `import массив from './data.json';`